# Make a Layout inactive in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` and in this `RelativeLayout` there are 4 `Button`s. Outside this `RelativeLayout` there is `CheckBox`.The whole `View` is in a `RelativeLayout`.

I want to make the 4 `Button`s to inactive (which are present in the `RelativeLayout`) by selecting on `CheckBox` and I want to make all the buttons active when I again select the `CheckBox`. so what to do ?

I have also tried `relativeLayout.setClickable(false);` but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UTDATE**

Try this:

```
<yourRelativeLayout>.setEnabled(false);
```

or you can change state of all your buttons to disabled.

Comment: I want to make the layout which contains 4 buttons to be inactive.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion . but relativelatout_ID.setEnabled(false) not working. It cant disable the layout .

Answer (score 1):

```
    final int[] BUTTON_IDS = { R.id.button1, R.id.button2, };

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            for (int btnId = 0; btnId < BUTTON_IDS.length; btnId++) {
                Button btn = (Button) findViewById(btnId);
                btn.setEnabled(isChecked);
            }
        }
    });
```